# In Ansible, How to connect to windows host?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have been stuck with Ansible window module. I am just trying to ping windows machine.But i get 'connect timeout'

**hosts**

```
[windows]
192.168.1.13
```

**group_vars/windows.yaml**

```
ansible_user: raja
ansible_password: myPassword
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

And While I run : `ansible windows -vvv -i hosts -m win_ping`

```
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
<192.168.1.13> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: raja on PORT 5986 TO 192.168.1.13
192.168.1.13 | UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.13', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fcb12024a90>, 'Connection to 192.168.1.13 timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))",
"unreachable": true
}
```

However I can ping that windows machine using `ping 192.168.1.13`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to prep your windows machine for PowerShell remote management, otherwise ansible won't be able to connect to it. For most features to work you will need at least [PowerShell 3.0 installed](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595) (which is only supported on  Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 SP1 and later versions), and also run [this script](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1), which will not only enable WinRM, but also install some necessary certificates for the connection to work.

Once you donwload the `ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1` file the following command from command line should do the job:

> powershell.exe -File ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1

Comment: At some point, it may be useful to use a versioned link, such as https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/c99c3b2b5d396b2cc1d25ad9aa6816aa922ffbc7/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 .  Beyond that, I'm wondering, does Ansible run this script automatically?  Do folks normally use Ansible (or some other WinRM based tool) to invoke this script?

Answer (score 2):

If you using fresh azure vm and aws ec2 and facing issue

```
"changed": false,
    "msg": "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='IP Address', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9650462390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))",
    "unreachable": true" "
```

**Solution:**
Just add below rules in windows VM in Inbound rules.

- **WINRM-HTTPS**
- **ICMP4**

Answer (score 2):

Note, the appropriate URL for the script referenced in the accepted answer is here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-documentation/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1, this is different from the URL in the accepted answer's comment section.*

This is mentioned in the Ansible issues section [ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 removed from default branch? #81240](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/81240#issuecomment-1632563399)

*I don't have sufficient reputation to add this as a comment to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you using fresh azure vm and aws ec2 and facing issue

"changed": false,
"msg": "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='IP Address', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9650462390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))",
"unreachable": true" "
Solution: Just add below rules in windows VM in Inbound rules.

WINRM-HTTPS
ICMP4

This is not specific enough.  Add these rules where and how.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these in your playbook.
that was solved for me.

win_ping.yml

```
---
- name: Test WinRM connection
  hosts: windows
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Test connection
      win_ping:
      vars:
        ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```